# How to populate a userform listbox/combobox Array/list from a textbox input?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to allow the user to input data in a textbox and have that data be added to the combobox array, how can I get it to save into the code?

[image]

I have some code that will populate the data for that session, but it disappears after I close the application.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   If TextBox1.TextLength > 0 Then
      UserForm1.ComboBox2.AddItem TextBox1.Value
      TextBox1.Value = ""
   Else
      Exit Sub
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   With ComboBox2
      .AddItem ".020"
      .AddItem ".030"
      .AddItem ".032"
      .AddItem ".040"
   End With
End Sub
```

I need the user to be able to input there data and have it be in the combobox for everyone else later on. Any help would be appreciated! Even search terms that could point me in the right direction.

Comment: You'd need to store the list somewhere in the document and give the user the ability to edit that list.  Maybe look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.customdocumentproperties  though values cannot be >255 characters in length, so if that's a problem you'd need a different solution, maybe look at CustomXMLParts eg - http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?37833-Solved-Reading-CustomXML

Comment: hi. u can use a sheet to store the values that the user put, and next use them to populate the combox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this. Have a sheet in your workbook called "Data". When the user adds something using commandbutton1 it goes to column A in the Data sheet and puts the users value in the next available row.

When you load the other form it will loop through column A and grab all the values and add them to combo box.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
        Dim lastrow As Long: lastrow = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

       If TextBox1.TextLength > 0 Then
          Sheets("Data").Cells(lastrow, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
          TextBox1.Value = ""
       Else
       MsgBox "Please enter a value"
          Exit Sub
       End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    For i = 1 To Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ComboBox2.AddItem Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value
    Next

    End Sub
```